# Spurious spaces in output of for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use a batch file to convert a file containing sql code into a single environment variable for use with the MSSQL utility bcp.
For example, if InFile.sql contains

```
-- This is a simple statement
SELECT *
    FROM table
```

The output of `ECHO %query%` should be
`SELECT * FROM people`

The code below works for me most of the time

```
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: Replace VarOld with VarNew
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('TYPE InFile.sql') DO ( SET line=%%a & ECHO !line:table=people! >> TmpFile1 )

:: Remove comment lines starting with  '-'  and remove newline characters
(FOR /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (TmpFile1) DO SET/p=%%a ) <nul >TmpFile2

:: Create variable 'Query'
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('TYPE TmpFile2') DO SET query=%%a
```

however, the first FOR loop adds 3 space characters at the end of each line and the second FOR loop adds another space character so the result is
`SELECT *     FROM people`

I could cope with the additional spaces (although the purist in me wasn't happy!) until I had to use it with a long SQL query and multiple replacement steps - every line in the file was having 12 space characters added.  The additional spaces are enough to make the resulting query around 8300 characters long - too much for Windows' 8196 character limit for a batch file line.

Can anybody see how I can remove these spurious spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tokens=*` in a `for` loop should trim whitespace as you're capturing a line of infile.sql.  Here's a proof of concept, echoing `%query%` contained within quotation marks to illustrate the trimming:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set query=
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage

for /f "usebackq eol=- tokens=*" %%I in ("%~f1") do (
    set "sub=%%I"
    set query=!query! !sub:table=people!
)

:: strip the leading space from %query%
echo "%query:~1%"
goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 sqlfile
```

**Example output:**

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>type infile.sql
-- This is a simple statement
SELECT *
    FROM table

C:\Users\me\Desktop>test.bat infile.sql
"SELECT * FROM people"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue is that trailing spaces ARE significant in SET statements and ECHO statements before the redirectors.

In your code, you need to remove the spaces after `%%a` and `people!` in the first `FOR` Thus:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('TYPE InFile.sql') DO (SET line=%%a&ECHO !line:table=people!>> TmpFile1)
```

The next problem is a little more subtle. In

```
(FOR /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (TmpFile1) DO SET/p=%%a ) <nul >TmpFile2
```

the space following `/p=%%a` is REQUIRED because it provides the separator between the text taken from the lines when building TmpFile2 - and that leads to a superfluous trailing space. Try replacing that space with a `Q` for instance - just for testing.

Hence, you need to delete the final space from `QUERY` after it's been constructed in your final `FOR`

```
SET query=%query:~0,-1%
```